# How can i set different css for admin side and front side with moodle?

Tags: php, mysql, themes, moodle

I am new to moodle portal understanding.Now my requirement is to use bootsmetro based front end.But applying that new theme it also getting applied on backend-admin side.So can any one support me how to resolve this issuue by the use of moodle functions and how can i put seperate css for both front and back.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want a different theme for the admin, or a different interface but using the same theme for the admin?

Comment: i want different theme for admin because in my front theme i am not going to provide any menus or else... it will only shows video according to categories...so as i am changing css and applying bootsmetro css its getting applied on admin so i cant see anything useful on admin end...so i want to include separate style sheet and js files for admin and front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could allow the user to choose their theme (have a look at [this page](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Theme_settings#Allow_user_themes)).

Follow these steps:

- Go to `Site administration > Appearance > Themes > Theme settings`;
- Enable `allowuserthemes`;
- Edit the admin profile to choose the desired theme for the administrator.